# Spring security - remember-me authentication with multiple authentication providers

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, remember-me

I'm using Spring security 3.2.0 in my web application.

I have two security roles: users with the credentials stored in database and administrators withe credentials stored in configuration file.

It works fine until I turn on remember-me authentication. Here is my `security.xml` config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:remember-me key="myAppKey" user-service-ref="adminSrv"/>
        <security:remember-me key="myAppKey" user-service-ref="jdbcUserSrv"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" id="jdbcUserSrv"
                                        users-by-username-query="/* SQL query */"
                                        authorities-by-username-query="/* Another SQL query */"
                    />
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="adminSrv">
                <security:user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" password="passwd"/>

            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

When I log in as administrator it goes fine.

When I try to log in as user it throws exception on j_spring_security_check:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /mercury/j_spring_security_check. Reason:

    user1
Caused by:

org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: user1
    at org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(InMemoryUserDetailsManager.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:262)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:298)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

However if it is authenticated successfully and if I open my application index page it is shown logged in as "user1".

If `remember-me` config for jdbcUserSrv goes before the config for adminSrv then the error appears for "admin" user.

Current configuration works fine without the `remember-me` options but I need them to be enabled.

Please advice me how to avoid these errors.

Comment: AFAIK, spring requires you have remember-me which expects a UserDetailsService bean. Mentioned on spring doc, http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two remember-me elements is simply overriding one another. Having multiple UserDetailsService instances can get you into trouble too. For example, I assume you likely have data associated with your users. If a user named admin exists in both the in memory and the jdbc UserDetailsService instances, then how do you know which admin user the data belongs to? For this reason, it is likely best to use a single UserDetailsService.

Alternatively you can create a UserDetailsService that delegates to multiple UserDetailsService instances. For example:

```
public class DelegatingUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final List<UserDetailsService> userDetailsServices;

    public DelegatingUserDetailsService(
            List<UserDetailsService> userDetailsServices) {
        this.userDetailsServices = userDetailsServices;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        RuntimeException last = null;
        for(UserDetailsService uds : userDetailsServices) {
            try {
                return uds.loadUserByUsername(username);
            } catch(RuntimeException error) {
                last = error;
            }
        }
        throw last;
    }
}
```

Then you can have remember-me use it instead:

```
<bean id="delegateUds" class="DelegatingUserDetailsService">
     <constructor-arg>
         <list>
             <ref bean="jdbcUserSrv"/>
             <ref bean="adminSrv"/>
         </list>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:remember-me key="myAppKey" user-service-ref="delegateUds"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decided to implement my own UserDetailsService but your solution is also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use remember me with Spring Security Java Configuration(Spring 5.0.6)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            //... nothingImportantToThisCase
            .rememberMe();
}
```

and multiple auth providers like this:

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
                            UserDetailsService userDetailsService) Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("ADMIN")
                    .password("{noopassword")
                    .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                    .and()
                .withUser("USER")
                    .password("{noop}password)
                    .roles("USER");
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

same exception will be thrown but still will be logged in.
But surprisingly this will work:

```
@Autowired
@Order(1)
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("ADMIN")
                    .password("{noop}password")
                    .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                    .and()
                .withUser("USER")
                    .password("{noop}password")
                    .roles("USER");
}
@Autowired
@Order(2)
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
                            UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

important thing is that even they have different method arguments, both must have @Autowired if only one need